# Rhel 7 : systemd fails to start a process if background option is given

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7, systemd, systemctl, rhel-7

I have a systemd unit file (serv_unit.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
StartLimitInterval=400
StartLimitBurst=3
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myscript start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/init.d/myscript**

```
source /etc/myfile.sh # JAVA_home & other vars are resolved through this file
mode=$1
case "$mode" in
  'start')
    # Start daemon
    daemon --user=abc $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $appClassPath $MAIN_CLASS $args &
```

The problem I am facing is when I run following command:

```
systemctl start serv_unit.service
```

I don't see java process. But when I remove the trailing **&** i.e.:

```
daemon --user=abc $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $appClassPath $MAIN_CLASS $args
```

the java process can be seen (& that java process is not crashing so that rules out the possibility of it crashing in background)

What is the cause?

Comment: Where does this `daemon` tool come from?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the main question, calling init.d scripts from systemd is a bit redundant and generally a bad idea to begin with. This is all you should need:

```
User=abc
EnvironmentFile=/etc/myfile.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $appClassPath $MAIN_CLASS $args
```

EnvironmentFile can only be plain KEY=value assignments, but if configuration must come in shell-script syntax, you can also use:

```
User=abc
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c ". /etc/myfile.sh && exec $$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $$appClassPath $$MAIN_CLASS $$args"
```

(You should also set `SyslogIdentifier=` in both cases, if the service produces stdout messages.)

### Service types

Systemd services are expected to follow specific rules. One `.service` unit can only have one "main" daemon process, and the `Type=` option tells systemd how that process works.

**`Type=simple`** indicates that the initial process (i.e. what's launched from ExecStart=) itself is the service's main process. As soon as the main process exits, the service is considered to have *stopped*, so any leftovers are cleaned up.

This means that if you're using Type=simple, you're telling systemd that the daemon *will not* go into 'background'. In fact, you're also telling systemd that *the init.d script* – not `daemon` – is the service's main process...

So it would be best if the init.d script not only didn't attempt to put the actual daemon in background, but also started it via `exec` like this:

```
case "$mode" in
    'start-foreground')
        # Start daemon in foreground
        exec daemon --user=abc $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $appClassPath $MAIN_CLASS $args
```

On the other hand, **`Type=forking`** indicates that the initial process *will* fork and exit during the startup procedure, and that the main process should be discovered from PIDFile= or heuristically.

#### Which one to use

With daemons which have *built-in* 'daemonize' mode, `Type=forking` has a significant advantage: the systemd service stays in 'Starting' state until the daemon finally tries to go into background, at which point it finally moves to 'Started/Active' state. This helps when configuring dependencies, e.g. service A can declare "After=B.service".

But if backgrounding is done by external means, such as the shell `&` feature – without anything that would report whether the daemon is ready or not yet – then it's completely *useless* and you should probably just use `Type=simple` without any background options.